# Magento: Store Credit Not Showing on Back-end of Customers > Manage Customers

Tags: customer

I'm trying to set up store credit on the back-end of my magento store. However, under:

Customers >> Manage Customers, there should be a section called "Store Credit" on the left hand sidebar. Unfortunately, not showing up on my end.

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: are you using a 3rd party extension for this or is it something you developed yourself?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Enterprise Edition, have you enabled it in System > Configuration > Reward Points?

[image]